# SE Data Explorer: Users by City

Tags: sql, stackexchange

I view users by city using this SQL query:

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Reputation DESC) AS [#], 
    Id AS [User Link], 
    Reputation
FROM
    Users
WHERE
 LOWER(Location) LIKE 'sulaimani, iraq' or LOWER(Location) LIKE 'erbil, iraq'
ORDER BY
    Reputation DESC;
```

This works.

I don't like the repetition of the `LIKE` clause - this could get unwieldy if I want to include many more locations (but not the whole country).

Comment: Does SEDE not support `LOWER(Location) IN ('sulaimani, iraq', 'erbil, iraq')`?  That would be a little bit more manageable.  I think that the `Location` value is free-form anyway, so could be difficult unless users are consistent and don't make spelling errors!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
>  LOWER(Location) LIKE 'sulaimani, iraq' or LOWER(Location) LIKE 'erbil, iraq'
> ```

It is not necessary to use `LIKE` if you want an exact match.  The `=` is sufficient in that case.

```
 LOWER(Location) = 'sulaimani, iraq' or LOWER(Location) = 'erbil, iraq'
```

And as @TobySpeight already [commented](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/266474/se-data-explorer-users-by-city#comment526447_266474), you can then change it to an `IN`.

```
 LOWER(Location) IN ('sulaimani, iraq', 'erbil, iraq')
```

That won't work if you want to actually use `LIKE` to do a fuzzier match, e.g.

```
 LOWER(Location) LIKE '%, iraq'
```

But in that case, you could create a [temporary table](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/5646/temporary-tables-indexes-and-procedures-work) with the data as you want and query that, possibly joining the original table.  By "data as you want", I mean lowercased and possible only the part after the ", " in this case.  For other queries, you might have different requirements.